# How to add dynamic inputs in react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have 3 inputs and plus button when pressed it I want to add another 3 inputs so with his state,

the state like this

```
state={
 toolsUsed: [
      {
        id: (Math.random() * 150).toString(),
        name: '',
        price: '',
        count: '',
      },
     {..},
    ],
}
```

in the first 3 input component, I want when I add a change value text set the state with this value!

but I tried it but after changing the text I got in a state

```
toolsUsed => [" ","text"]
```

what I want to achieve

```
toolsUsed => [{name:'text",count:'..',price:'....',id:'..'},{...}]
```

UI

[image: UI]

here's my code

```
renderToolsUsed = () => {
   const {toolsUsed} = this.state;
   const prom = toolsUsed.map(({name, id, price, count}, i) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={name =>
                this.setState(
                  prevState => {
                    return {
                      ...prevState,
                      toolsUsed: [prevState.toolsUsed[i].name, name],
                    };
                  },
                  () => console.log(this.state.toolsUsed),
                )
              }
              value={name}
              key={id}
            />
          </View>


          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={count => this.setState({})}
              value={count}
              key={id}
            />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.toolsItem}>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={price => this.setState({})}
              value={price}
              key={id}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
          this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              toolsUsed: prevState.toolsUsed.length + 1,
            };
          })
        }> **// heres i got error "toolsUsed.map not a function**
            <Text>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });

     return prom;
   }
```

**JSX**

```
...
render(){
  return(
      <View style={styles.toolsContainer}>
            <Text>
              Tools
            </Text>
            {this.renderToolsUsed()}
        </View>
     );
 }
```

EDIT~1

maybe :D solve plus function

```
 onPress={() => {
                let newInput = this.state.toolsUsed.length;
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                  toolsUsed: prevState.toolsUsed.concat([newInput]),
                }));
         }
```

**EDIT ~ 2**

I add a minus button to delete the last object in tools array,
here two ways to handle it, but I have something **weird** on the first way it's work well I don't know why! but when I comment first var `newInput` it's don't delete the last item

```
onPress={() => {
        // first way
         let newInput = this.state.toolsUsed.pop();
         this.setState(prevState => ({
              toolsUsed: prevState.toolsUsed.filter(
                 tool => tool.id !== id,
               ),
         }));
       // Second
         let rowDeleted = [...this.state.toolsUsed];
         rowDeleted.splice(-1, 1);
         this.setState({toolsUsed: rowDeleted});
 }}
```

Comment: Using a random generator to produce a unique id is not a great idea.

Comment: @Kobe hmm, why?

Comment: Why would it be a good idea? If you depend on an `id`, then you're burying a bug, since it won't happen often, but it will happen, that is, generating the same `id`.

Comment: well, how can I generate `id`

Comment: By starting from 0 and work your way up? That's a common approach

Comment: treat the ID like an index for each 'row' of controls. You can assign each instance something more permanent when it is going to its final storage location (api/db/local storage)

Comment: great maybe i will replace this random with an index of when using an iterated array, but i made this issue with other cases e.g when I send an order to firebase I make a random id, I don't know how to start from 0 then increase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something like this in the state update. It's not pretty, but your edit of the state is pretty deep.

This should edit the name of the i'th element in the toolsUsed property of your state:

```
onChangeText = {name =>
    this.setState(
        prevState => {
            return {
                toolsUsed: [
                    ...prevState.toolsUsed.slice(0, i),
                    {
                        ...prevState.toolsUsed[i],
                        name
                    },
                    ...prevState.toolsUsed.slice(i + 1)
                ],
            };
        },
        () => console.log(this.state.toolsUsed),
    )
}
```

Note that your `TouchableOpacity onPress` also breaks your state. It replaces the array with a number.

Your edited function still doesn't add a correct new entry to the array. It should add an object with the same structure. It should look something like this:

```
onPress={() => {
    let newInput = {id: generateId(), name: '', price: '', count: '',};
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        toolsUsed: [...prevState.toolsUsed, newInput],
    }));
}}
```

As you mentioned in the comments, the last fix missing was adding stable keys to each View in the mapped array, like this: `<View key={i} >..</View>`

Comment: Thanks for the response, for `setState` It's work, but when I type just first character of a word the keyboard disappear and so on

Comment: I gave my code a bit more context. If you replace your `onChangeText` with this one, you still lose your array when editing the name?

Comment: I think the issue is i put map inside render() so in every re-render, i will lose it

Comment: Doing the map shouldn't be a problem. It's pretty natural and it's a non-destructive operation. Your problem has to be with mutating the state. It just occurred to me that your map is executed on an object that is not obviously `this.state.toolsUsed`.  What is `toolsUsed` from `renderToolsUsed`?

Comment: Sorry, it's from the state I forget to add it !

Comment: Hey @artcorpse, when i add a key for parent view in `map()` like this `<View key={i} >..</View>` it's work fine! have you any idea about it? **before** I add a random key to parent View by using Math.random()!

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Your array was no longer getting corrupted, but you were getting a new Input field each time, because you didn't have stable keys on your array elements. Adding the same key to the view with each render ensures continuity for that view. The view will be reused, and then the state of the input field will continue to be the same.

Comment: Great, I got it, so I think you see my function for plus btn it's a good way? because i want to handle the empty field before the user adds a new row of the input

Comment: I updated my response to reflect a small correction for the plus btn.

Comment: Great, it's work well, what the difference between my Edit and yours? and for knowledge, the `generateId()` should not be a random id as mentions in the question comments, how can i handle it?

Comment: The difference is that you were not adding a new object to the array, but a number, and that will lead you to problems when you do things like `this.state.toolsUsed[this.state.toolsUsed.length - 1].name`.

Comment: For the generateId issue, please create another stackoverflow question. This one is already getting pretty big, and out of scope.

Comment: Hello @artcorpse again, sorry about that, but i have a question related on ur answer, I want to add a minus "-" button that deletes object of same array "Tools"  how can i handle it?

Comment: Can u check the EDIT ~ 2 section, please?